# trying to understand arguments in js

Tags: javascript

```
function f(message)
{

  console.log(message,arguments);

}

f("H", "e", "l", "l", "o");
```

It shows: H + ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

Question:

why message only shows `H`, not `["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]`?

Comment: Message = H and arguments is all what is passed in function

Comment: Why do you want to pass the wrong number of arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing 5 arguments to the function:

```
function test(arg1,arg2,arg3){
  console.log(arg1);//=1
  console.log(arg2);//=2
  console.log(arg3);//=3
  console.log(arguments);//[1,2,3,4,5]
}
test(1,2,3,4,5);
```

The arguments variable is a special variable that contains all the function's arguments.

Because you can use the arguments variable you can leave out the arg1,arg2,arg3 part intirely:

```
function test(){
  console.log(arguments[0]);//=1
  console.log(arguments[1]);//=2
  console.log(arguments[2]);//=3
  console.log(arguments);//[1,2,3,4,5]
}
test(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Usually people don't do this because it's unclear what to pass to the function. To make it even more clear what your function is supposed to return and what variables you should pass to it you can use JSDoc. Many IDE's use this to show more info on the method when auto completing/code assisting it.

```
/**
 * Gets user By Id
 * @param {Number} id
 * @returns {User}
 */
var getUserById=function(id){
    return u;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Message is the first parameter you are passing to the function, in this case the `"H"`, `arguments` it's an array-like object that holds *all* the parameters you pass in.

Some info:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)
- [Another explanation](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/)

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is you're passing 5 arguments into f here. Since you have only one param in the function, only the first argument is assigned to `message`.

However, the other four, as you know, are still in the `arguments` pseudo-array.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `f` has only one parameter and you are passing **5 separate values or arguments** and since you only one parameter to receive it then only the `1st parameter` which has the value of **'H'** is the one only accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `f` accepts only one argument i.e. `message`. But during the function call you are passing 5 arguments i.e. `"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"`. If you want the whole of this to be available in message then either pass using any one of the following methos:

1. In single string `f("Hello")`.
2. Concatenated string `f("H" + "e" + "l" + "l" + "o")`
3. or Pass it as an array `f(["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"])`

The `arguments` variable is an internal function handling mechanism of javascript i.e. whenever you pass parameters to a function it gets assign to the variables that function has defined in its signature but an array list of  those variables is also maintained in the function variable called arguments.